Why do I need to execute a getch() before ncurses will display anything?
I have an curses application with a getch() loop.
I found that the application would only display after accepting user input.  In other words, I could not draw anything to the terminal before accepting user input; I had to do it after.  This code fixes it:
stdscr.nodelay(True)
while stdscr.getch() != -1:
    pass
stdscr.nodelay(False)

But it doesn't take this much.. just running a single getch() and discarding the return value allows ncurses to do it's job, and render the screen as intended. Without that, nothing is drawn to the console (other than maybe the blank screen)!
What happened?
Edit
I have been advised to include a minimally reproducible example.  This code here:
import curses

def main(stdscr):
    # Initialize ncurses
    curses.curs_set(1)  # Show the cursor
    stdscr.clear()
    # Get screen dimensions
    height, width = stdscr.getmaxyx()
    input_win_height = 4
    output_win_height = height - input_win_height - 1

    # Create windows
    input_win = curses.newwin(input_win_height, width, 0, 0)

    currentCommand=""
    max_height, max_width = input_win.getmaxyx()
    outputRow=0

    inData={"row": 2, "col":1,"window":input_win}

    #stdscr.nodelay(True)
    #stdscr.getch()  # Drain the input buffer
    #stdscr.nodelay(False)

    def setCommandWindow(inData):
        inData["row"]=2
        inData["col"]=1+1
        inData["window"].clear()
        inData["window"].box()
        inData["window"].addch(2,1, ">")
        inData["window"].refresh()

    setCommandWindow(inData)

    while True:
        key = stdscr.getch()
        setCommandWindow(inData)

    print("Quitting the application")
    if __name__ == "__main__":
         curses.wrapper(main)

If you uncomment those lines, it starts up and draws a box.  If you do not uncomment those lines, it starts up to a blank screen, and draws a box only after getting a character.

Are you doing anything before the code you currently show? Are you doing some input operation? Perhaps an input operation that might leave characters still in the input buffers (like a newline)?

You don't think that key = stdscr.getch() in the loop might have something to do with the box being drawn after you give some input? Perhaps you should change the order of the statements in the loop?

The posted code defines a function, but doesn't run it. It also contains at least one typo. Have you actually run this code on your computer?

I copied and pasted it.

This question is similar to: Text added to New window is not visible in Curses. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.  Better yet, read the documention.

You copied and pasted the code including the wrong indentation which is important in Python?
